# Azure AD B2C Email Signature

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Is there any way of changing the email signature sent by Azure AD B2C?

The signature sent by default is the name of the directory and I need to change it

Answer (score 1):

In your Azure AD B2C tenant:

1. open the Microsoft Entra ID service (search for it in the search bar if it's not in your recent list).
2. Open the properties blade (under manage section)
3. Change the 'Name' field.

[image: Image of tenant properties blade]

It is this 'Name' field that is displaced on the default Azure OTP Emails:

[image: Microsoft default OTP email]

The only other alternative is to plugin your own email provider, such as SendGrid, which is only available with Custom Policies via the Identity Experience Framework.

Comment: This will not change the directory name? I'd like to only change the signature

Comment: The directory identifier {yourtenant}.onmicrosoft.com and login urls {yourtenant}.b2clogin.com will not change, but yes, in the change directory blade of the azure portal, it will be displayed with the name provided in that box.

There is, unfortunately, no way to disconnect what is on the email signature and what is displayed in the azure portal switch directory blade without using custom policies and your own email provider.